# Resetting original display drivers

Tags: 12.10

When I first installed Ubuntu on my system, the display worked pretty much exactly how I wanted it to. I decided that it couldn't hurt to install drivers through jockey-kde. This made the screen resolution horrible and tiny, so I deactivated it, but now my display settings appear to be bare bones and medicore. I'd really just like to reinstall the display portion and have ubuntu re-auto-configure it, but I don't know how to do this without reinstalling Ubuntu alltogether.

I'm running 12.10 Desktop, btw.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When installing ubuntu it uses the standard Xorg driver that almost works with every graphical card, but this driver can be slow and blurry. Can you provides us what more information over your card? So we can give you some more info about installing your driver correctly.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the response. My card is a GeForce GTX 660. I downloaded the driver from the NVidia website and tried to install it manually via "sh driver-name.run" but it kept giving me errors. I had stopped the x server as it had requested. And then it mentioned something about part of the kernel(?) that needed to be removed in order for the installation to work properly. The installer offered to remove it for me, and I let it. But it kept saying the installation failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing the nvidia driver correctly run these command in the following order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313
sudo reboot
```

I have used this commands succesfully on a GTX670 and a 315M.

Comment: It works. Thank you! Ubuntu looks beautiful now.

Comment: Looks great, but the HDMI sound doesn't work anymore as it did with the default drivers. Any ideas? (I did try going into sound settings and changing it to HDMI, but it still doesn't work)

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I got it working by going into sound settings and choosing a different profile. Weird there are several of the same named profiles, but only one of them works.

Comment: I am happy for you that it worked ;). Only thing you need to know is that you now have a newer linux kernel. So watch out with some kernel updates from ubuntu itself. Also i recommend to do `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean your boot partition a bit ;).

Comment: So I'm curious why I needed to update my kernel.

Comment: Because the drivers from xorg-edgers are compiled with that kernel.